# How to turn off text replacement sync between iPhones

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

Similar questions have been asked but aren’t exactly what I need, I added some text replacements to my mum's iPhone because she has random words autocorrect to full capitalisation (e.g. "can’t" to "CANT" - if anyone can offer a solution to that too would be good) but since I’ve added them to her phone they’ve synced to mine, so I get them too. I can’t figure out how to turn it off.

I’ve tried turning off iCloud syncing, I've deleted them from my phone but they then delete off hers. This is purely between two iPhones no Mac or iPad involved. neither options worked for me.

Comment: Why are you signed into the same iCloud account? You should use Family Sharing or only share an account for purchases.

Comment: Can you add links to those similar questions so people don‘t recommend the same solutions again?